# addEventListener is not working in plnkr editor while executing script in external file

Tags: javascript, html, plunker

Here is my first [link][1] where I have used script tag internally and addEventListener is working fine.

Here is my second [link][2] where I have used script externally and addEventListener is not working.

```
  [1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/f8vd7pGijNFxghz56Aze?p=preview
  [2]: https://plnkr.co/edit/i1pKKwdSC0O2o3FvhoD4?p=preview
```

Comment: You've misidentified the problem. As well as moving the source code from inside the script element to a URL with a `src` attribute … you **moved the entire script element** to a different part of the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your script to the end of body or add the listerners in `window.onload` handler.

https://plnkr.co/edit/KvKLCC2QOFdTTEHcmiCl?p=preview
https://plnkr.co/edit/6skW5rucm73my9pK6cGw?p=preview

Comment: What I have to do if I want to add it externally in js

Comment: Have you read the answer?